# Vim 'expandtab' leaves leading whitespace

Tags: vim, indentation

I have some C code, with `⇦` pointing to the character where Vim's cursor is located and `·` indicating a leading space.

```
int main()
{⇦
····return 0;
}
```

I currently have 'expandtab' turned on, and I press 'O', yielding:

```
int main()
{
····⇦
····return 0;
}
```

I press the 'Enter' key once, and now I have:

```
int main()
{
····
····⇦
····return 0;
}
```

I press the 'Enter' key one more time, and write some text, giving:

```
int main()
{
····

····// bla bla bla⇦
····return 0;
}
```

How do I make Vim not put that leading indentation on the first line after the `{` ?
It is smart enough to remove leading spaces on **subsequent** empty lines.

If I reindent the file with `gg=G`, that extra space is removed. But it should not be there in the first place, from what I understand.

Also, if I do not have 'expandtabs' turned on, everything works fine.
In other words, if I do the same as above with 'noexpandtabs', there is no extra indentation left hanging around.

Is there a setting somewhere to fix this?
Is it a bug?

My version is: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Apr  5 2012 10:17:30)`

---

**Updates:** some more information

---

I can reproduce this with a fairly 'vanilla' set of settings, such as by invoking Vim with: `vim -u /etc/vimrc foo.c`, and then in the session running `set expandtab` and `set cindent`. I have also tried 'set autoindent', which doesn't seem to help for this particular case.

The `ci`, `si` and `ai` settings are all disabled.

I am running on CentOS 6.4, for reference.

Thanks

Comment: This behavior can be very plugin dependent. I could not reproduce your problem with the Fedora and Gentoo Vim install.

Comment: @matthiaskrull What versions of Vim were those?

Comment: pls report the output of these commands: `set ci?`  `set si?` and `set ai?`

Comment: 7.3, 7.4 and now an Ubuntu vim that comes close to your build (VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Nov 15 2012 00:35:35) with `:set autoindent cindent smartindent expandtab`

Comment: @Kent: updated at the end of the question. They are all off.

Comment: @matthiaskrull: Could I bother you to try with `vim -u /etc/vimrc foo.c`, then turning on `expandtab` and `cindent` (I added info at the end of my question) ?

Comment: @jwd With ai, si and ci disabled you should get no automatic indentation at all. With `vim -u /etc/vimrc foo.c` still not reproducable on all tested versions.

Comment: @matthiaskrull I had a typo in my comment, I meant `cin` (cindent), not `ci`.. but I guess this was clarified by OP's other comments. he had `cindent` on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be a wily plugin causing the issue.

I should have tried with `--noplugins` earlier (didn't know about that option).

I had the '[ctab.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=231)' plugin in effect this whole time. Disabling it fixes the issue.

Also, there is a bugfix  for this issue provided by Konstantin Lepa at this site: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Script:231

Answer (score 1):

You need `set ai`

from help:

```
'autoindent' 'ai'       boolean (default off)
                        local to buffer
        Copy indent from current line when starting a new line (typing <CR>
        in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O" command).  If you do not
        type anything on the new line except <BS> or CTRL-D and then type
        <Esc>, CTRL-O or <CR>, the indent is deleted again.  Moving the cursor
        to another line has the same effect, unless the 'I' flag is included
        in 'cpoptions'.
        When autoindent is on, formatting (with the "gq" command or when you
        reach 'textwidth' in Insert mode) uses the indentation of the first
        line.
        When 'smartindent' or 'cindent' is on the indent is changed in
        a different way.
        The 'autoindent' option is reset when the 'paste' option is set.
        {small difference from Vi: After the indent is deleted when typing
        <Esc> or <CR>, the cursor position when moving up or down is after the
        deleted indent; Vi puts the cursor somewhere in the deleted indent}.
```

note that

> **If you do not
>               type anything on the new line except <BS> or CTRL-D and then type
>               <Esc>, CTRL-O or <CR>, the indent is deleted again.**

Comment: Alas, it does not work for me. The crux for me is that it behaves one way with `expandtab` on, and another with it off. Autoindent doesn't seem to change either case.

Comment: @jwd you said in your comment, `cindent` was on, right? so basically, you tested with `cin` and `ai` on, it didn't work?

Comment: Yes, correct. I run `vim -u /etc/vimrc foo.c`, then use `set cindent expandtab` (with or without `autoindent` as well), type the file as written above, and perform the steps described, and I have a line with extra whitespace. Easy to see with `set list`

Comment: @jwd, I do this with vim7.4, no leading spaces:. `vim -u /etc/vimrc foo.c` `set expandtab|set cindent|set ai` then copy your text, follow your steps (`O, Enter etc`),